# Mount remote file object to Carrierwave in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I am currently developing an app using AngularJS and Ionic framework and Rails as the backend.

In my app, i want to add an attachment and upload and save it via Carrierwave in Rails. so basically, my angularJS adds the attached file and then i pass the attached file object to rails and mount it on carrierwave. Does anyone know how to do it.

here is my code

attach_file.html

```
<input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="picFile" name="file" accept="image/*" ngf-multiple="true" ngf-max-size="20MB" required>
```

controller.js

on Submit it executes this function

```
$scope.uploader = newData.file;
createNewRealEstateCase.submitImageAttachment($scope.uploader.$modelValue, real_estate_agent_assignments_id).then(function(result) {
   console.log(result)
})
```

this service function calls this method in my rails controller.

```
def image_attachment_by_loan_application 
    ap params
    @rea_attachment = RealEstateAgentAssignment.find(params[:real_estate_agent_assignment_id])
    params[:attachment].split(",").each { |image| 
      @rea_attachment.real_estate_agent_assignment_attachments.create(real_estate_agent_assignment_id: params[:real_estate_agent_assignment_id], attachment: image)
    } 
  end
```

It runs with no errors but the file object doesnt get uploaded and remains empty.

How do i mount a remote file object to carrierwave in rails? I know how to mount the remote image url once it has been uploaded somewhere else but this is basically mounting a remote file attachment object in carrierwave in rails.

Any help is appreciated,

Comment: What does your `RealEstateAgentAssignment` model look like? What does your uploader look like?